# Firestore update document with WHERE

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```js
async () => {
const doc = await firestore().collection("queue").where("order_id", "==", elem.orderID)
}
```

Here is the code of mine. The question is, how to update a document without knowing its document ID. Is it feasible by a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `firestore().collection("queue").where("order_id", "==", elem.orderID)` you just define a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query) but you don't fetch any data.

I make the assumption that this query will return a unique document. Therefore you need to **execute** the `Query` with the `get()` method and, then, **update** the unique document returned by the Query, as follows:

```
async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await firestore().collection("queue").where("order_id", "==", elem.orderID).get();
  await querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({...})
}
```

Note how we use the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property of the `QuerySnapshot` which returns "an array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`."